# Create layers on PowerPoint slide?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

Is it possible to create a layer (programmatically) on a specific slide in PowerPoint?

A layer here I mean a place holder that is allowed to contain multiple shapes. If we delete this layer, all its sub-shapes will be deleted.

Note: I am using visual studio ultimate 2013, C#, vsto, powerpoint 2013, and 2010.

Comment: Not possible. You could say that PPT doesn't have layers, or that each shape sits on its own layer.  You can, however, group multiple shapes; this produces a single shape that's effectively on its own layer and if the group shape is deleted, all the shapes that constitute the group are deleted.

Comment: Your answer is good. I think it should be the answer of this post.

Comment: Thanks ... I've edited it a bit and added it as an answer in case you'd like to mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in PowerPoint.

You could say that PPT doesn't have layers, or you could say that each shape sits on its own layer.

But you can group multiple shapes; this produces a single shape that's effectively on its own layer and if the group shape is deleted, all the shapes that constitute the group are deleted.